# Finding the last character of a file and adding a string after that?

Tags: text-processing

Appending an extra line is simple as I can use `echo "line" >> file` but what if I want to add a string right after the last char in the file without starting a new line? What are some good ways to do this?

Comment: `echo -n "line" >> file` will avoid placing an additional newline at the end.

Comment: @don_crissti The title says after last character, the body suggests otherwise. So let us ask the questioner. user3669481 can you clarify for us?

Comment: OP pretty clearly meant "last character" to mean the last visible character, not considering that most people would consider the newline to be the last character

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A well-formed unix text file *must* have a trailing newline at the end of the file.  To achieve what you want, the string must be placed *before* that *existing* trailing newline.

Consider this test file:

```
$ cat File
1
2
3
```

Now, let's add words to the last line *before* the last newline character:

```
$ sed '$s/$/new words/' File
1
2
3new words
```

Or, if you want to edit the file in place, use the `-i` option:

```
sed -i.bak '$s/$/new words/' File
```

How it works:

- `$`

  The first `$` tells sed to only perform the command which follows on the last line of the file.
- `s/$/new words/`

  For that last line in the file, this places `new words` at the end of the line but *before* the final newline character.

  In a substitute command, `$` means end of the line.

Comment: Excellent answer! I am faux-XML tagging some plain text (processed emails) so that I can import it more easily into PostgreSQL -- somewhat analogously to my SO answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007884/import-xml-files-to-postgresql/49950384#49950384.  My input file (e.g.) is: "Unclogging the body's protein disposal system ... in patients with AD."  I can tag that text with `sed -i '1s/^/<BODY>/ ; $s/$/<\/BODY>/' input_file`, giving "<BODY>Unclogging the body's protein disposal system ... in patients with AD.</BODY>".

Answer (score 1):

To avoid rewriting the entire file you would seek to the end of the file, back up one character and write.

Doing this with regular Unix shell tools is a bit iffy.

However, there's Perl, which does everything. You could also use Ruby or Python or any other full featured script language.

Perl example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use Fcntl qw(:seek);

open(F, '+<', 'testfile') or die "$!";
seek(F, -1, SEEK_END) or die "$!";
print F "new data\n";
close(F) or die "$!";
```